# Trouble using Google's SafeBrowsing Module

Tags: python, python-module

I am quite new to python, and am trying to import the "googlesafebrowsing" module (available [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-safe-browsing/downloads/list)) into python. Looking at the python docs, [here](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html), it mentions to unzip/tar the file (done), cd into the directory (done), and then pun a command similar to this:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, there is no setup.py available in this directory, or more importantly... there is no README file (otherwise I would not be here). The following is a list of the files in this directory:

```
[root@matt-dev googlesafebrowsing]# ls -lrt
total 196
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   922 May 10  2011 util.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10919 May 10  2011 server_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 24479 May 10  2011 server.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9999 May 10  2011 sblist_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12047 May 10  2011 sblist.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     0 May 10  2011 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  1865 May 10  2011 hashprefix_trie_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  4095 May 10  2011 hashprefix_trie.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 10327 May 10  2011 expression_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 11623 May 10  2011 expression.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  3043 May 10  2011 datastore.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 11358 May 10  2011 COPYING
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   965 May 10  2011 client_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 14701 May 10  2011 client.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  3507 Apr 21 15:00 datastore.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  8947 Apr 21 15:00 expression.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   873 Apr 21 15:00 util.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  4072 Apr 21 15:00 hashprefix_trie.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 27861 Apr 21 15:00 server.pyc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 11886 Apr 21 15:00 sblist.pyc
```

Has anyone used this module in their python instance? - Any suggestions on what I should do.

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To let Python successfully import the googlesafebrowsing module, the goglesafebrowsing directory needs to be in a directory that is contained in sys.path.  To do that, you could move the directory to e.g. ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, or set a PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable to make Python look into an extra directory to find modules.  You should find more info about that in the official doc, precisely the distutils doc, the doc for the site module in the library reference, and the doc about Python environment variables in “Python setup and usage” (all of them on docs.python.org).  The tutorial may also help.  You can also write a simple setup script yourself and run setup.py install to let Python move the files to somewhere appropriate:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='googlesafebrowsing',
      version='0.3',
      packages=['googlesafebrowsing'])
```

(A package in Python is just a special kind of module that is actually a directory containing submodules including a special one named `__init__`.  A module is something that can be imported, commonly a file with the .py extension.)
And then:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

(The --user option is explained in the distutils install docs.)

Finally, I think you should ask the developers of that module to provide a setup script.